# Firebase addr - timeout connection

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I found a edge case that I would like to confirm with others:

For some clients they cannot use Google Firebase because their connection timeout. I found they are not able to establish a connection with any Firebase Project.

Firebase projects always try to connect to: subdomain.firebaseio.com this domain always resolve to the same IP Address: 35.201.97.85

E.g.:

```
➜  ~ dig +short another-project.firebaseio.com
35.201.97.85
➜  ~ dig +short some-project.firebaseio.com
35.201.97.85
➜  ~ dig +short any-project.firebaseio.com
35.201.97.85
```

And for the clients with issues I found the router is blocking the connection:

```
traceroute to 35.201.97.85 (35.201.97.85), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.100.1 (192.168.100.1)  5.878 ms  2.816 ms  3.262 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
```

For now all the clients have in common, they are Telekom Romania and the router with problem seems to be a Huawei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record, I am investigating a similar issue and I found it very odd that this is the only meaningful search engine hit, and I am Romanian.

My current theory is that the IP was provider blocked by the recent initiative of the Romanian Cybersecurity Directorate to block various fake news sites, which ended up in press: https://economie.hotnews.ro/stiri-telecom-25439056-dnsc-spune-lucreaza-remedierea-problemelor-bookblog-site-recenzii-carti-fost-blocat-fara-preaviz-motiv-implicat-atacaturi-ddos.htm ( I remembered there was a Firebase mention in the article and what do you know, there's the IP :) ). This question was posted on March 11th, same day as the update that included the RT Firebase URL, so it checks out.

Currently I'm having this problem from the Vodafone mobile network, but it's very likely that various providers decided to block the IPs as well.